# Socket Traffic Byte Duplication (?)

Tags: python, c++, sockets

I'll try to keep things concise.  I'm working with a raw binary network trace that I'm replaying against a service that can parse its contents.  My rough-shod python client works like so:

```
with closing(Telnet('localhost', 5001)) as conn, open(fname, 'rb') as trace:
  for seq, source, packet in split(trace):
    conn.write(packet)
```

This works (mostly) as expected.  It is received in C++ with code that looks like this:

```
string temp(8192, '\0');
int status = ::recv(socket, &temp[0], 8192, 0);
```

The problem demonstrates only for byte sequence `ff`, which is duplicated.  A 21 byte packet *works*:

```
Send: 000000150000000e00000001000000050005d6e480
Recv: 000000150000000E00000001000000050005D6E480
```

A 29 byte packet does *not* - it is received as *30* bytes:

```
Send: 0000001d0000000e000000010000000d000dd63380f400ff0000030203
Recv: 0000001D0000000E000000010000000D000DD63380F400FFFF0000030203
```

A 53 byte packet also fails, reporting *57* bytes on the remote side:

```
Send: 000000350000000e00000001000000250008d68f001600000008d633000c0001000ed68f001700003840ffffffff0007d68f80f300
Recv: 000000350000000E00000001000000250008D68F001600000008D633000C0001000ED68F001700003840FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0007D68F80F300
```

With a more arbitrary sequence, and the resulting received side:

```
Send: 54ff68ff69ff73ff20ff69ff73ff20ff61ff20ff74ff65ff73ff74ff2e # chr(255).join('This is a test.') - length 29.
Recv: 54FFFF68FFFF69FFFF73FFFF20FFFF69FFFF73FFFF20FFFF61FFFF20FFFF74FFFF65FFFF73FFFF74FFFF2E // length 43
```

Wat?

Comment: But your 21-Byte packet doesn't have `ff` in it.

Comment: But _why_ is `ff` duplicated?  It should _not_ be.  Where are the extra `ff` bytes _coming from_ when I send over a packet that _happens_ to contain them?  They are _not_ in the client payload before I call `conn.write`.

Comment: I realise that, and I don't know why. But you are stating that a 21-Byte packet works, but 29 or 53-Byte packets don't. The length thing is probably irrelevant, but nobody can tell until you actually try a 21-Byte packet containing `ff`.

Comment: Show us more of your code for both the sending and receiving side. It's difficult to tell if this is UDP or TCP.  We can't see how you are treating the `status` variable returned by recv.  We can't see how you are generating those hex strings.

Comment: wireshark (or some other network monitor) should at least show what is put on the wire, because now, you don't even know where the duplication is done.  Also print the status of ::recv() to see how many bytes is actually received.

Comment: Also here's a fundamental clue to what I think is your misunderstanding. The fact that you call these packets, but it appears that you are using TCP with send/recv calls. TCP is a stream protocol, not a packet protocol like UDP. Hence, you might send N bytes on one side, but it may take multiple recv calls before you see all the bytes on the other side.

Comment: @selbie - While I appreciate your sentiment, I can assure you I understand how packets work.  The connection is TCP, but that's unimportant in this situation.  You'll notice that the duplication occurs _mid-content-stream_.  The sequences both before and after the duplicated bytes are correct.  The call to `::recv` is the Windows API Call.  The python hex representations are generated with `binascii.hexlify`, and the c++ with `boost::algorithm::hex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is related to telnet protocol. The byte `0xff` [means in telnet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231866) interpret as command IAC, which comes before telnet commands. For example:

```
IAC BRK 0xff 0xf3
IAC EL  0xff 0xf8
```

The sequence `0xff 0xff` is used to escape this IAC in order to send `0xff`.